# how i can back up my ubuntu server?

Tags: server, php, backup

I have an ubuntu lamp server and some other settings and configurations.
i can create back up by exporting mysql databases and create copy of php files but how i can create a full clone/backup of all operation system with all configurations/setting/users/... on it?

is there any built in tool or step by step tutorials for doing this?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7417/what-way-is-best-for-backing-up-apache2-mysql-cvs-and-webmin-configuration-fil?rq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/176884/how-do-i-backup-a-server?rq=1

Comment: Is the information on a single partition or spread over multiple partitions?

Comment: Clonezilla. http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone  The link is a step by step guide.

Comment: i think there is just one partition that all of os installed on it.

Comment: "of all operation system" don't. You should focus on a backup that only backs up your files and have a setup where you can re-install the OS, restore a backup and have the system running again. This also allows you to reinstall to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

### How to Create Exact Copy of Your Linux Server Disk Drive and Restore it

Use `lsblk` to locate location of your hard disk.

if your hard disk is located at `/dev/sdb` then use the following command to make a replica image of your entire disk into an image, which you can restore on

- Another hard disk
- USB Flash Drive ( if big enough )
- Another Linux Server

### Copy entire disk over SSH

`ssh -p 22 -C root@my-server "dd if=/dev/sdb bs=1024k conv=noerror,sync" | \
dd of=MyServerDisk.iso`

This will create an entire copy of your disk to your local machine using `-C` Compression.

To restore it unto another disk or USB do:

Assuming new disk drive is located at /dev/sda, then do:

`dd if=MyServerDisk.iso bs=1024k of=/dev/sda conv=noerror,sync`